# ASP.NET MVC Uploading with Extra Data and Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, upload

I am following an example from another question for uploading with jQuery.

http://aspzone.com/tech/jquery-file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-without-using-flash/

I would like to extend this a bit to add more data to the upload though, through other form elements. Any idea how this could be done?

Comment: Do you want to add more upload elements, or other elements like textareas, selects, etc?

Comment: More elements like textboxes and such.

Comment: Having tried this and spent a lot of time on it i'd suggest a two step process: (1) Post the non file data and persist it then (2) upload the file and attach them later. Trying to do both at the same time opens you up to so many potential problems that i so can't fit here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you have linked to does a post of the form `ajaxUploadForm` using the jQuery `ajaxForm` function.  I would presume that extra input data will be included when you add input elements to the `ajaxUploadForm` form.

Try it out: change the markup to the following (borrowed from the site in question):

```
<script type="text/javascript">   1:  
    $(function() {

        $("#ajaxUploadForm").ajaxForm({
            iframe: true,
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSubmit: function() {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").block({ message: '<h1><img src="/Content/busy.gif" /> Uploading file...</h1>' });
            },
            success: function(result) {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, result.message);
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").unblock();
                $("#ajaxUploadForm").resetForm();
                $.growlUI(null, 'Error uploading file');
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="ajaxUploadForm" action="<%= Url.Action("AjaxUpload", "Upload")%>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <fieldset>
     <legend>Upload a file</legend>
     <label>File to Upload: <input type="file" name="file" />(100MB max size)</label>
     <input type="text" id="someOtherInputElement" value="Test" />
     <input id="ajaxUploadButton" type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: No, this is not the case. There is no way to access these form elements on the Controller, is the problem. At least not that I can see.

Comment: Why was this answer marked as accepted? As with @Ciel, I don't see how to access these other elements in the controller action. Any insight on that?

Comment: Stacey, camainc: the goal of the ajaxForm function here is to package up the ajaxUploadForm form's input elements into a JSON object.  This object will then be interpreted by the MVC engine when processing the controller action.  If you ensure that the controller has the necessary parameters, this should work.  For reference, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656232/pass-object-from-json-into-mvc-controller-its-always-null.