# Pass object from JSON into MVC Controller - its always null?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I have seen a few questions on here related to the a similar issue, I have read them, followed them, but still i have the same problem.

I am basically creating an object in javascript and trying to call a method on the controller that will return a string of html.  Not JSON.

I've been playing around with dataType and contentType but still no joy.  So apologies if the code snippets are a bit messy.

Build the object in JS.

```
function GetCardModel() {
    var card = {};
    card.CardTitle = $("#CardTitle").val();
    card.TopicTitle = $("#TopicTitle").val();
    card.TopicBody = $("#TopicBody").data("tEditor").value();
    card.CardClose = $("#CardClose").val();
    card.CardFromName = $("#CardFromName").val();
    return card;
}
```

Take a look at the object - all looks good and as it should in JSON.

```
var model = GetCardModel();
alert(JSON.stringify(GetCardModel()));
```

Make the call...

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Postcard/Create/Preview/",
            dataType: "json",
            //contentType: "application/json",
            data: GetCardModel(),
            processData: true,
            success: function (data) {
                alert("im back");
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);
                //alert(error);
            }
        });
```

Always when I step into the controller, the object is ALWAYS there, but with null values for all the properties.

Comment: Well, don't edit the mistake out of your question.  Makes it tougher to see what Darin found!  (`data` above was `date` in [the first version](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/4656232/1), natch)

Comment: That wasn't the problem, it was a typo in the question. Always read the comments on answers

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The parameter name should be `data`, not `date`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/Postcard/Create/Preview/',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        CardTitle: $("#CardTitle").val(),
        TopicTitle: $("#TopicTitle").val(),
        TopicBody: $("#TopicBody").data("tEditor").value(),
        CardClose: $("#CardClose").val(),
        CardFromName: $("#CardFromName").val()
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('im back');
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
    }
});
```

which will successfully call the following controller action and the action parameter will be properly bound:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Preview(Card card) { ... }
```

with the model below:

```
public class Card
{
    public string CardTitle { get; set; }
    public string TopicTitle { get; set; }
    public string TopicBody { get; set; }
    public string CardClose { get; set; }
    public string CardFromName { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yeah that was a typo...sorry.

Comment: @SteveCI, OK please see my update, but even with the external function it worked fine for me.

Comment: my model is that, but with a couple extra props.  OK, it is now passing to the model to the controller, but I needed to tweak it like you said except to change dataType to text and add in contentType to application/json - which is the one that was stopping the data being passed.  removed processData - not sure what that does or defaults to.

Comment: for the data i now have JSON.stringify(GetCardModel()).  do i need to stringify ?? well it works so i guess so.

Comment: @SteveCI, `JSON.stringify(GetCardModel())` goes with `contentType=application/json`. This indicates that you are passing JSON to your controller action. But this works out of the box only in ASP.NET MVC 3. In previous versions you need to write a custom model binder so that it can accept JSON. As far as the dataType parameter is concerned this indicates the return content type. So if your controller action returns Json you need to set it to JSON. If your controller action returns content you could set it to text.

Comment: thanks so much for your explanation - its always great to get more than - do this and it works ... now I understand why and how!

Comment: I just had `public string PropertyName` instead of `public string PropertyName { get; set; }` and that was the issue in my case.
Thanks!

Comment: Note that if you are not expecting json back from the server, either change to the appropriate dataType or remove altogether. See docs for various dataType values: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I came across this because I was using "GET" instead of "POST". Is such a thing possible with "GET"? I was using HttpGet attribute on my controller method. Changing everything to post is fine and doesn't hurt my feelings, but I was wondering if it was possible with get. Thanks!