# How to save a single record with knockout

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js

I have a basic table set up using knockout, but I was wondering if there is any way to edit/save a single record, rather than having to save the entire view model every time a change is made? Here's my code...

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: movies">
    <tr> 
        <td data-bind="text: title"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: releaseDate"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: genre"></td>
        <td data-bind="text: price"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Edit" id="edit"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="editable"> <!-- hide this initially, only show when edit button is   clicked -->
        <td><input id="titleInput" data-bind="value: title" /></td>
        <td><input id="releaseDateInput" data-bind="value: releaseDate" /></td>
        <td><input id="genreInput" data-bind="value: genre" /></td>
        <td><input id="priceInput" data-bind="value: price" /></td>
    </tr>
 <!-- save button/form or something here containing ONLY this record -->

</tbody>
</table>


<script type="text/javascript">

function Film(data) {
    this.title = ko.observable(data.Title);
    this.releaseDate = ko.observable(data.ReleaseDate);
    this.genre = ko.observable(data.Genre);
    this.price = ko.observable(data.Price);
}

function MovieListViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.movies = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.title = ko.observable();
    self.releaseDate = ko.observable();
    self.genre = ko.observable();
    self.price = ko.observable();

    $.getJSON("/Movies/GetAllMovies", function (allMovies) {
        var mappedMovies = $.map(allMovies, function (movie) { return new Film(movie)    });
        self.movies(mappedMovies);
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new MovieListViewModel());
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, through the magic of **[binding contexts](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html)**, this is quite easy!

1. **Step one**. Place the following element anywhere inside your foreach template.

   ```
   <button data-bind="click: $root.saveMovie">Save</button>
   ```
2. **Step two**. Add the `saveMovie` method to your viewModel

   ```
   self.saveMovie = function(movie) {
       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "/someurl",
           dataType: "json",
           contentType: "application/json",
           data: ko.toJSON(movie),
           success: function(result) {
               //...
           }
       });
   }
   ```

The `movie` variable will contain the item of your foreach loop! Why? Because in Knockout, we have the amazing feature called binding contexts:

> A binding context is an object that holds data that you can reference
>   from your bindings. While applying bindings, Knockout automatically
>   creates and manages a hierarchy of binding contexts. The root level of
>   the hierarchy refers to the viewModel parameter you supplied to
>   ko.applyBindings(viewModel). Then, each time you use a control flow
>   binding such as with or foreach, that creates a child binding context
>   that refers to the nested view model data.

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: the only problem I'm having now is getting this to the controller... I've looked at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656232/pass-object-from-json-into-mvc-controller-its-always-null and when I do this... window.location = '/Movies/SaveMovie?movie=' + movie; inside the self.updateMovie method, it calls the method, but the data isn't properly mapped or something, wondering if you had any thoughts? Here's the controller method (with details view) : public ViewResult UpdateMovie(MovieViewModel movie)
        {
            return View("TestView", movie);
        }

Comment: Can you post the code for saveMovie()?  In there, you should be creating a JSON object that reflects the MovieViewModel and doing a $.post.  Or posting a FORM back that represents the MovieViewModel.

Comment: Ok. From my iPhone so may not be pretty:  $.ajax({
          url: '/echo/json/',
          data: ko.toJS(movie),
          type:'post',
          success: function(data) {

            },
          dataType: 'json'
        });

Comment: @Martin Devillers thanks I have almost the same thing... I think part of the issue is that (just for testing purposes) I'm having that controller method redirect me to another page (not just merely saving the update)... takes me to a page with the record's details... public ViewResult UpdateMovie(MovieViewModel movie)
        {
            return View("TestView", movie);
        }

Comment: Right that didn't work out well. Let me explain the steps: first, you need to create a controller action (or webapi) that accepts POST request. You do not want to do this on the query string because that is not proper design. Use Ko.tojs(movie) to convert your movie variable to json. Use ajax to call your action from JavaScript. Make sure to use the right verb and content type.

Comment: @Martin Devillers thanks a lot, I'll try that out tomorrow when I get some time

Comment: @barronick No problem. I've updated my original answer with some additional code. Good luck! :)